# Como formatear la fecha con moment.js, utilizandolo en vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Actualmente tengo el siguiente template:

Donde basicamente recorro el arreglo de objetos `listado_historial`
en tales objetos existe la propiedad `item.fecha` el cual los valores son timestamp:

**"1552680430061": corresponde a viernes, 15 de marzo de 2019 14:07:10.061 "1552673714691"**: **corresponde a viernes, 15 de marzo de 2019 12:15:14.691**
según https://www.epochconverter.com/

```
<template  v-for="(item, index) in listado_historial" v-bind="index">
              <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title>Tiempo: {{item.tiempo}} </v-list-tile-title>
                  <v-list-tile-sub-title class="text--primary">{{isToday(item.fecha)}}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
                  <v-list-tile-sub-title>Subtitle 2</v-list-tile-sub-title>
              </v-list-tile-content>
              <v-divider 
                v-if="index + 1 < listado_historial.length"
                :key="index">
              </v-divider>
            </template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
   methods: {
    isToday(date) {
            return moment.unix(date).format('L');
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

El inconveniento que tengo es que utilizando moment.js no logro obtener la fecha de esa forma o similiar, mediante el metodo `isToday`, lo imprime de la siguiente forma: 06/26/51172 y 04/09/51172.

De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece ser, según la [documentacion](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) del método `unix`, que ese método espera **segundos** y tú código está pasándole **milisegundos**.

```
isToday(date) { 
    return moment.unix(date / 1000).format('L');
}
```

Dividiendo los milisegundos entre mil para obtener los segundos debería ser suficiente.

Para que funcione con milisegundos, sin tener que hacer ninguna comprobación ni manipulación, el método ideal sería:

```
isToday(date) { 
    return moment(date).format('L')
}
```

Comment: Opino que seria mejor utilizar `moment(date).format('L')` ya que este método si puede recibir milisegundos.

Comment: Si claro, sería lo ideal, mi respuesta era si por algún motivo tuviese que usar `unix` si o si. Edito la respuesta